# Fixed Element on Android going appearing offscreen

Tags: android, html, css

I have a fixed footer with bottom: 0. It works fine except on android it is appearing below the screen. I have some other fixed elements that are also appearing off screen. For some reason I cant container them within the screen I've searched around and tried a view things but no joy. My guess is that if I change something in the viewport it will fix it. The image was taken from google chrome emulating the site on an S4 but the same problem persists on my actual phone also. The code for the footer should just make it sit at the bottom and it works fine in other browsers. I can change the value of bottom to around 26px then the whole footer becomes visible on the screen but that is not the fix I want. Any ideas?

[image]

```
.footer-fixed{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #111;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i've had this issue before,
but only on android versions lower then 4.4, so maybe you could tell me what android version you are working on,

try adding:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

to your

```
    <head></head>
```

on Android < 2.3 devices for elements that are fixed behave as "STATIC", (thats why your top element could be functioning normally, because its the first element and pushes the rest down)

Android 2.3 supports it but u need to disable viewport scaling as i think once written by bradfrost cant exactly remember, it was a while ago

if you experience flickering of the elment try adding

```
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to your css class, or even extend it with

```
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); makes some devices run their hardware acceleration.
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

its solves the flickering, but the thing is on some android versions you only need to add the backface-visibility hidden and on some the other 2 rules (trial and error). i should go for the first one, (at first) because adding the translate 3d, will drain more battery

anyways if its just a website try the solution above,

if you are making a cordova app, try adding https://crosswalk-project.org/ which add their own webview to your cordova package solving all these browser quirks on android.

--
a sidenote

when a element has position fixed, its display will be set to block,
and you have width: 100% on your elment, so if you are not using box-sizing:border-box;
the element would have a width of 100% + padding + margin added to it, 
i don't know the rest of your css, maybe you are setting margin or padding by a container class which is
(check the metrics of your element with chrome inspector)

If this is the case you could do 2 things
change display

```
width: 100% to auto;
```

or add: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

```
box-sizing: -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

or add normalize: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to your project, above your own css (link tag) within the head (Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.)

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I will try these out and get back to you

Comment: Also I'll get the version of android

Comment: It was the viewport! I changed it before I asked the question but I wasn't saving the file properly. Thanks again for your help!